# Post Redirect Get seems to be working but results JSP displays nothing

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, post, servlets

The gist of it:  I have a JSP form (`MyForm.JSP`) that takes user input and passes it to my first servlet (`"/myfirstservlet"`).

This servlet handles the SQL insert of the user input values into my `Fruits` table and then redirects the user to my results servlet (`"/results"`).

My results servlet then checks for the an `"ADD"` parameter and if "true" (i.e. it equals `"success"`) it finally redirects the user to my Results JSP (`Results.JSP`) which is stored inside the path:  `WEB-INF/MyFolder/Results.jsp`.

My JSP form (`MyForm.JSP`) is also stored inside the path:  `WEB-INF/MyFolder/MyForm.jsp`

Everything runs without an error on the console, but why is nothing displaying for my Results JSP (which now has the URL: `"results?ADD=success"` ???

My JSP form (`MyForm.JSP`):

```
<form action="myfirstservlet" do="POST">
   <input type="text" name="fruit"><br>
   <input type="text" name="color"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My first servlet (`"/myfirstservlet"`):

```
protected void doPost(...){
   String fruit = request.getParameter("fruit");
   String color = request.getParameter("color");

   String sql = "INSERT INTO fruits (fruit, color) VALUES" + "(\"" + fruit +  "\", \""  + color +  "\");";

   utilitySQL.sqlInsert(sql); // My utility class that handles sql inserts

   response.sendRedirect("results?ADD=success");
}
```

My results servlet (`"/results"`):

```
protected void doPost(...){

   response.setContentType("text/html");    

   if (request.getParameter("ADD").equals("SUCCESS"))
      request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/MyFolder/Results.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

My Results JSP (`Results.JSP`):

```
<body>
<h1>Results JSP</h1>


   <%ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) 

   utilitySQL.sqlSelectAll("Select * FROM fruits;");

   for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
   {%>
      <div><%=list.get(i)%></div>
   <%
   }%>

</body>
```

1.)  Am I implementing the **Post-Redirect-Get** properly?

2.)  Why is nothing displaying on my Results JSP?

**EDIT:**

If I remove the `"ADD=success"` parameter condition from my Results servlet (`"/results"`) then my Results JSP displays the values from my MySQL database, but if I add the `"ADD=success"` parameter my Results JSP displays nothing.  Why is this so?

Comment: What is there in utilitySQL? have you committed data in sqlInsert?. You should add code used in sqlSelectAll & sqlInsert.

Comment: Yes, I  am sure I have committed the insert since I can view my database itself using PhpMyAdmin.  There is no problem in my utitlitySQL class.

Comment: The newly created list is not referencing to the output of select query. Hence the size of list will be always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in `"/myfirstservlet"` replace  `response.sendRedirect("results?ADD=success");` to  `response.sendRedirect("/results?ADD=success");`

Second in `"/results"` servlet method should be `doGet`. You used `doPost`. And in this servlet instead of using `if (request.getParameter("ADD").equals("SUCCESS"))`  use 
`if (request.getParameter("ADD").equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"))`.

Third in your `result.jsp` I think

```
<% ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) utilitySQL.sqlSelectAll("Select * FROM fruits;");
```

there is a problem. Because you are getting list of object. It sould be

```
<% ArrayList<Your class name> list = (ArrayList<String>) utilitySQL.sqlSelectAll("Select * FROM fruits;");
```

And in this section

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)

       {%>
          <div><%=list.get(i)%></div>
       <%
       }%>
```

Your are trying to print complete object.

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing anything because of this line:

```
 if (request.getParameter("ADD").equals("SUCCESS"))
```

`.equals()` is case sensitive. You are checking for "SUCCESS" but you are passing "success" as the value.

So that means this line will never run:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/MyFolder/Results.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Therefore blank page.

You can either send the value in uppercase or change `.equals()` to `.contains()`

Comment: why it takes you to the results page if you take away the parameter, i'm not sure. But i'm guessing it might have something to do with a null pointer exception. (it's worth checking for null before evaluating for equals().. otherwise you will get a nullpointer exception)